# How to run React Native app on ios simulator and ios device at the same time on different ports?

Tags: react-native, port, ios-simulator, metro-bundler

currently running my app on port 8081 and it works fine on both simulator and real device but when i run simulator with --port 8082 i get the following error:

[image]

I just want to run app on two different devices to test out push notifications.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: react-native run-ios --simulator='iphone 14' for simulator from your VS terminal and run in your device from selecting your iPhone in Xcode by running your .xcworkspace file from your ios folder. For different port use this command ~ react-native start --port 9988 , it'll help you specify different port.

Comment: still getting error when i run on port 8082

Answer (score 0):

following these steps:

```
(1) open ios file project with code
(2) in the project bundle delete main.jsbundle file
(3) add a new empty file by main.jsbundle name
(4) Run command: react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
now react-native run-ios
```

Comment: still getting error when i run on port 8082